# Are there separate parameters/weights in LSTM cells for each timestep?

Tags: lstm, rnn

As I understand, the parameters and weights of a basic RNN is the same for each time step - there is only 1 set to train. Is this also the case for standard LSTM cell?

More specifically, these are the equations for the standard LSTM cell on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory):

\begin{aligned}f_{t}&=\sigma _{g}(W_{f}x_{t}+U_{f}h_{t-1}+b_{f})\\i_{t}&=\sigma _{g}(W_{i}x_{t}+U_{i}h_{t-1}+b_{i})\\o_{t}&=\sigma _{g}(W_{o}x_{t}+U_{o}h_{t-1}+b_{o})\\c_{t}&=f_{t}\circ c_{t-1}+i_{t}\circ \sigma _{c}(W_{c}x_{t}+U_{c}h_{t-1}+b_{c})\\h_{t}&=o_{t}\circ \sigma _{h}(c_{t})\end{aligned}

Are there separate/distinct $W$'s and $U$'s for each timestep?